# Disable back button in angular2

Tags: angular

When on the redirect url after the payment gateway , want to disable the back button in angular 2.I have tried to use  window events beforeunload and onPopstate , None of them seem to work

I have also tried to use window.history.forward but does not work 
.Please suggest!

Comment: you cannot disable back button of browser. Instead you should show a message to user that they shouldn't press back button.

Comment: The message can also be added if the event gets caught , these events are not caught  on my page which is a redirected page after payment. it works on other pages but only when I add some url in the history

Comment: This is what I have done for the first page and it works host: <code>
{
    '(window:popstate )': 'onWindowScroll($event)'
  },history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname); 
  onWindowScroll(event: Event): void {
    if (confirm("You have already checked out, do you still want to exit")) {
      history.go(-1);
    }
    else {
          history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
      
    }
  }  

</code>  But this doesnot work for redirected page after the payment

Answer (score 5):

You can use AuthGuard in angular 2 to suffice your requirement. You just need to implement CanActivate and write your business logic

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate() {
   if (localStorage.getItem('payment')) { //key to indicate that user has visited payment gateway (you can change as per your needs)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

**Routing**

```
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: homeComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }
```

Hope it helps!!